# Google Cloud Workflow error as "Syntax error: Unclosed string literal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I am trying to create google cloud workflow by following [this post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/automate-the-execution-of-bigquery-queries-with-cloud-workflows-9fffe0557dbb) by Marton

I am trying to execute a big query procedure using cloud workflow and while executing the procedure, I need to get the last update timestamp of the table as I want to merge only those records in my target table which came later. I need only delta records.

Below is my cloud workflow code.

```
main:
  steps:
    - getList:
        call: BQ_Query
        args:
          query: >
              SELECT 
              TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
              FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__` where table_id='table_name'
        result: items
    - data :
        call: BQ_Results_LoopItems
        args:
          items: ${items.rows}
        result: res

BQ_Results_LoopItems:
  params: [items]
  steps:
    - getupdatetime:
        call: BQ_Task
        args:
            table_id: ${items[0].f[0].v}
        result: result
   

BQ_Task:
  params: [table_id]
  steps:
    - delete:
        call: BQ_Query
        args:
         query: >       
              DECLARE last_update_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL;
              DECLARE source_dataset_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
              DECLARE source_table_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
              DECLARE destination_dataset_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
              DECLARE destination_table_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
              DECLARE recordstamp_column_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
              DECLARE flag_column_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
              DECLARE is_deleted_column_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
              DECLARE hash_id_column_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
              DECLARE pk_colmun_name_list ARRAY<STRING> DEFAULT NULL;
              CALL `project.dataset.procedure_name`("$table_id"", 'dataset', 'table','dataset', 'table', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', ['column5','column6','column7'])
        result: queryResult
    - documentFound:
        return: ${queryResult}



BQ_Query:
    params: [query]
    steps:
      - runBQquery: 
          call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.query
          args:
              projectId: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
              body:
                  useLegacySql: false
                  query: ${query}
          result: queryResult
      - documentFound:
          return: ${queryResult}
```

I am doing all this to get last update timestamp for the table.
I am not sure if this is right way but I am getting error as below

```
HTTP server responded with error code 400
in step "runBQquery", routine "BQ_Query", line: 55
in step "delete", routine "BQ_Task", line: 31
in step "getupdatetime", routine "BQ_Results_LoopItems", line: 21
in step "data", routine "main", line: 12
{
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": 400,
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "location": "q",
          "locationType": "parameter",
          "message": "Syntax error: Unclosed string literal at [1:600]",
          "reason": "invalidQuery"
        }
      ],
      "message": "Syntax error: Unclosed string literal at [1:600]",
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
  },
  "code": 400,
  "headers": {
    "Alt-Svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"",
    "Cache-Control": "private",
    "Content-Length": "371",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "Date": "Fri, 09 Jul 2021 17:25:46 GMT",
    "Server": "ESF",
    "Vary": "Origin",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "X-Xss-Protection": "0"
  },
  "message": "HTTP server responded with error code 400",
  "tags": [
    "HttpError"
  ]
}
```

I am not able to troubleshoot this error. is there any issue with syntax while calling the variable for last update timestamp? Kindly ignore the naming convention and variable name. I am just trying to get it right first

Comment: Did you try with your query inline, instead of using `>`

Comment: Hi @guillaume blaquiere . Yes, I have tried that but same issue. I have used > in other workflows for big query but not sure what is missing here. I am wondering if I am correctly passing table_id parameter in "BQ_Task:" for last update timestamp. I haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere, I further investigated and looks like the problem is definitely with table_id. I provided a timestamp value instead of table id while calling the procedure in BQ_Tsk subworkflow and the workflow executed all fine. I am not sure what is wrong with passing as an argument. Looks like I should be passing +table_id based on https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/subworkflows?hl=FA, but  it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @guillaume blaquiere, I created another question for the error with respect to big query. Its here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68334540/executing-a-bigquery-using-google-workflow-to-get-last-modified-of-a-table-gett, The issue is with workflow executing the value for last modified time. date value is fine.

Comment: In the BQ_task that you are  running as part of the workflow, $table_id is enclosed with the extra double inverted commas (“ ) so is the error "Syntax error: Unclosed string literal at [1:600].